# Dual Boot Windows 11 + Ubuntu on two separate 1TB SSD, How to share data?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, ssd

I have finally fulfilled my dream of dual boot Ubuntu / Windows. Everything is also running well with both respectively. Mainly I use it for the university, whose most important data I synchronize with each other via Onedrive and Dropbox. Now I'm thinking about what would be a useful way to exchange data between both systems. With Ubuntu, you can access the data on Windows (even if you have to click through the C partition again and again to get to the folder you are looking for in Documents). With Windows you can probably use ext2fsd.

However, I'm now considering creating a third partition (no idea if I'll create it on the Windows or Ubuntu SSD) where I'll store data that can be accessed by both. This way I save myself unnecessary duplication for data outside the cloud, so to speak. However, this is where I worry that problems could arise. For example, if I store Python code on this partition, will Ubuntu or Windows be slower to compile the code? Might format problems occur?

Comment: If I create my new partition on the Windows SSD and need to access a file in that partition quickly and often via Ubuntu due to save/read in a Python code, doesn't that cause longer call times than if the file were on the Ubuntu SSD? And can't this cause problems that I'm not seeing right now? I mean that my new partition must be in NTFS format, otherwise Windows will have trouble. Would not this also cause problems when accessed through Ubuntu?

Comment: Assuming the volume is already mounted, its irrelevant if files are not on the same drive as the root file system .  The only thing that matters is the read speed of the disk itself. Ubuntu knows how to work with NTFS, but Windows does not know how to handle ext# file systems, nor does Windows know how to handle *NIX ownership or permissions. So the only restriction using a NTFS file system is that you can't store things there that need *NIX ownership or permissions. This is a non-issue for documents and similar files.

Comment: You also need to disable Fast Startup in Windows. Same process as Windows 10: https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-turn-on-or-off-fast-startup/